# DOM addEventListener while looping in Parse.com Query

Tags: javascript, dom, parse-platform, onclick, addeventlistener

I decide to move my (not so complex) app from Firebase.com to Parse.com. So my previous snippet in DOM that worked fine since yesterday to dynamically create N forms doesn't pass, anymore, the parameters correctly.

Here my snippet (i cut a lot of repetitive istructions):

```js
function displayForms() {
 while (divBot.hasChildNodes()) {
   divBot.removeChild(divBot.lastChild);
 }
 query.find({
 success: function(results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   // Ok suppose that my results was something like
   // Position 0. ID = "Tom" and other things
   // Position 1. ID = "Mark" and other things
   // Position 2. ID = "Ivan" and other things
   
   var object = results[i];
   var id = object.id;
   
   var form = document.createElement("FORM");
   var fieldset = document.createElement("FIELDSET");
   var inputId = document.createElement("INPUT");
   inputId.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
   inputId.value = id;
   fieldset.appendChild(inputId);
   
   var buttonDel = document.createElement("INPUT");
   buttonDel.setAttribute("type", "button");
   buttonDel.value = "Elimina";
   console.log(id);
   // HERE i have "Tom" at first iterate
   // "Mark" at second and "Ivan" at third
   // I also printed "i" and i have 0, 1, 2
   buttonDel.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // HERE i have "Ivan" all the times
    // I also printed "i" and i have always 2
    // So i am passing always the last value
    del(inputId.value);});
   
   fieldset.appendChild(buttonDel);
   form.appendChild(fieldset);
   divBot.appendChild(form);
   }
 },
 error: function(error) {
 alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);}
 });
}
```

Comment: Oh it was definitely duplicate sorry but that title tricked my research lol i will never search "infamous" in my life xD, shall i delete?

Comment: It's up to you. But I think you can mark it also as duplicate which will close the question directly.